# Insert FlexTable in Leaflet PopUp

Tags: r, leaflet, flextable

Is there a way to insert Flextables in leaflet Popups? I have tried several ways, including converting the Flextable to HTML code. I would like to do it directly from the Flextable code without transformation to htmlTables package or similar. Here is a sample code:

```
lat <- c(43.22693)
lon <- c(-86.20437)
```

> ```
> map <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 18)) %>%
>   addTiles()%>%
>   setView(lng = -97, 
>           lat = 39, zoom = 4) %>%
>   setMaxBounds(lng1 = -180, 
>                lat1 = -60, 
>                lng2 = 180, 
>                lat2 = 65) %>% 
>   addCircleMarkers(lat = lat, lng = lon, popup = flextable(mtcars)) 
> map
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(leaflet)
library(flextable)

lat <- c(43.22693)
lon <- c(-86.20437)
map <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 18)) %>%
  addTiles()%>%
  setView(lng = -97, 
          lat = 39, zoom = 4) %>%
  setMaxBounds(lng1 = -180, 
               lat1 = -60, 
               lng2 = 180, 
               lat2 = 65) %>% 
  # addCircleMarkers(lat = lat, lng = lon, popup = to_html(flextable(mtcars), type = "html")) #default
  addCircleMarkers(lat = lat, lng = lon, popup = to_html(flextable(mtcars), type = "img")) # as an image
map
```

Comment: Tx. But i get this error: Error in UseMethod("to_html") : 
  no applicable method for 'to_html' applied to an object of class "flextable"

Comment: hum, do you have the latest version (`0.8.6`)?